# Docker container date/time totally different to host PC

Tags: date, time, docker

When I run a docker container on my PC it has a totally different date/time to the host PC. See commands below. The time on the container recognizerDev is for the previous day, different hour, different minutes to the host. Any idea what is going on?

```
PS C:\Users\Bobby> date
11 October 2016 19:51:38

PS C:\Users\Bobby> docker exec recognizerDev date
Mon Oct 10 21:43:54 UTC 2016
```

When I try the same thing running on an AWS linux host the date/time is correct except for a 1 hour difference due to timezones.

Note that the first command returns the correct time/date in UTC+1 (London) as per my PC. The second command says it is in UTC but this cannot be right as if so it would return the same result less 1 hour.

Comment: What timezone is your host machine using?

Comment: UTC + 1 (London). Note that the first command gives the correct UTC+1 date/time. The second command is incorrect for UTC (as returned in the output) - I'll clarify in the question.

Comment: I've just reset docker on the PC and the time is now correct though it wasn't when it had come up automatically at PC boot time. It seems that when it first comes up when I boot the pc it has the wrong time, but if I reset it, it gets the right time. I'll try to confirm this and if so put it as an anser.

Answer (score 7):

This is only a partial answer (because it does not necessarily resolve the problem), but may help with diagnosis.

When you are running docker under Linux (as on your AWS host), you are just running processes on the host.  That is, there isn't a substantial difference between `docker run fedora ls` vs running `ls`, except that the former has a slightly different view of system resources.  The time reported in the container will always match the time reported on the host, modulo timezone settings.

When you running docker anywhere else (e.g., under Windows or MacOS), there is an additional layer in play: docker spawns a Linux virtual machine (historically using VirtualBox, although I think they may [take advantage of other options these days](https://blog.docker.com/2016/03/docker-for-mac-windows-beta/)) and then runs docker inside the virtual machine.

Because this is effectively a different machine from your host, it is possible for the time to drift.  There are various ways of solving this sort of problem, including running ntp inside the virtual machine or running special guest agents that take care of keeping time in sync with the host. I don't know enough about how Docker configures these systems to know how or if they handle this explicitly.

If your docker vm has been running for a long period of time, simply restarting it may resolve the problem.  Possibly [docker machine restart](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/restart/) is what you need.

Comment: Thanks that is all useful. I've certainly restarted the container, rebuilt the container, and of course the engine restarts every time my PC restarts. I haven't tried a machine restart. I'll report back if that makes a difference.

Comment: When I try the docker-machine commands on powershell, e.g. docker-machine ls, returns an empty list, docker-machine active, returns "No active host found". This despite the fact I have a container running as shown when I do docker ps. So still can't change to the correct time which is causing me problems now. Any ideas?

Comment: I've just reset docker and the time is now correct. It seems that when it first comes up when I boot the pc it has the wrong time, but if I reset it, it gets the right time. I'll try to confirm this and if so put it as an anser.

Answer (score 4):

To some people looking on still how to correct the date and time, not sure if this will work to you but it happens on me using windows.

Just have to restart the locker, and once the docker booted up, it will sync time and time to the localhost machine :)

Comment: This fixed my time drift problem. It seems that putting your laptop on sleep with Docker running can cause this

Comment: I figured out it was docker where the time was wrong, Didn't realise restarting it would fix the issue

Answer (score 2):

**If you don't want to restart the docker then the following script can synch time by and disabling and re-enabling time synch through Windows PowerShell**

$vm = Get-VM -Name DockerDesktopVM

$feature = "Time Synchronization"

Disable-VMIntegrationService -vm $vm -Name $feature

Enable-VMIntegrationService -vm $vm -Name $feature

Comment: The term Get-VM is not recognized as the term of a cmdlet....

Answer (score 0):

You can try specifying that you wish to get the time settings from the host PC by adding the following lines to the docker compose file

```
volumes:
- /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
- /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
```

Answer (score 0):

restarting my PC resolve the problem for me.