# How do I *correctly* fix SSL certificates on the raspberty pi?

Tags: ssl, raspberry-pi, debian

I'm trying to fetch something via HTTPS but I get an SSL error. I've just now (2017-08-13 13:20) run the following:

```
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude upgrade
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py  # <-- This resulted in the error shown below
sudo aptitude reinstall ca-certificates
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py  # <-- This resulted in the same error
```

Looking at `https://bootstrap.pypa.io` on my desktop browser looks fine. I inspected the SSL certificate and it looks ok. As a quick-check: The browser tells me it's "secure".

As I've updated the `ca-certificates` package, I don't know what else could be the issue.

The error:

```
--2017-04-10 12:34:25--  https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
Resolving bootstrap.pypa.io (bootstrap.pypa.io)... 151.101.36.175
Connecting to bootstrap.pypa.io (bootstrap.pypa.io)|151.101.36.175|:443... 
connected.
ERROR: The certificate of ‘bootstrap.pypa.io’ is not trusted.
ERROR: The certificate of ‘bootstrap.pypa.io’ is not yet activated.
The certificate has not yet been activated
```

Output of `lsb_release -a`:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 8.0 (jessie)
Release:        8.0
Codename:       jessie
```

Comment: There's obviously the option to use `--no-check-certificate` on `wget`, but that isn't the best idea if you're having this issue. Have you verified that it is not (somehow?) being intercepted? Also have you tried using `curl` instead to ensure it is not `wget` causing the issue?

Comment: yes. Tried curl. It also complains about the SSL cert. I am also aware about the option to wget, but instead of circumventing the problem I would like to understand how this is actually happening and how I can fix it.

Comment: You noted that you've reinstalled `ca-certificates`, is `ssl-cert` installed/up-to-date? Also, confirm that the date on your device is correct (`date`). If it is off by a couple days you could be seeing this due to that; and it seems like this is the issue, as it says the certificate has not yet been activated (i.e. it is before the valid-from date).

Comment: Hmm... this is weird. I see indeed the incorrect time. I updated `/etc/timezone` and ran `ntpd -gq` but the time is still WAY off. I also set local NTP servers. Not that it should make a difference but while I was at it I could pick something from this continent ;) Still, no luck. FWIW, the previous `/etc/timezone` entry pointed to UTC, the new one links to the local timezone.

Comment: Okay... I now manually set the date using `date` and `wget` successfully downloaded the file. So the SSL errors were indeed related to time. If you'd like, format your above comments as comprehensive answer and I'll accept it. In the mean-time: Any idea why `ntpd -gq` still gives me an incorrect time (tried again: It actually does nothing at all)?

Comment: I've made mention to a few things in my answer that might cause that which I've found... Not an ntpd expert though (I've not used it much), so your mileage may vary.

Comment: I saw. Thanks for the information. Not an ntp expert either. I did not get it to work. I kind of hope that NTP will now do the right thing again as the date is within it's range where it accepts skewing the values. Still weird that I can't get `ntpd -gq` working though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wget --no-check-certificates` exists, but as you say, you want to find the root issue. Rightly so, as certificate issues aren't really something to mess around with, even if they are just benign.

You mentioned that you've tried reinstalling `ca-certificates`, and `ssl-cert` should be installed with that or not required. That leaves two issues I can think of: the date, or you have some kind of strange configuration for wget somehow changing how it handles cert dates. That said, the fact that `curl` gives the same error means it would be a system configuration, and I can't think of anything that would cause this in that category.

This output, however:

`ERROR: The certificate of ‘bootstrap.pypa.io’ is not trusted.
ERROR: The certificate of ‘bootstrap.pypa.io’ is not yet activated.
The certificate has not yet been activated`

Gives it away. I expected it to not be this and instead be some kind of esoteric configuration option, but some things are easy to overlook -- and having tried everything else, I fell back to suspecting time. Knowing that a certificate must be within a date range to be considered "active," an error saying that it is not activated would mean that it is outside that range. This typically means that the clock of the device you are running wget on is not correct, or the cert isn't valid yet (or has expired, but the tense doesn't give that meaning -- i.e. isn't valid *yet*).

Visiting the website, I see that your certificate is valid, but also only 3-4 days old, which is a small enough margin of error for many issues like this. Had you waited some extra time, the issue would've resolved on its own eventually (as long as the cert doesn't expire before the OS would see it as valid).

Try running `date` or `hwclock` to make sure your clock is correct. If not, update it with `date --set`, `ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com`, or `ntpd -gq`.

I had a similar problem when setting up pis (one of them was off by a year if I recall). I'm not sure what causes this to be so severe on some, but not on others.

I don't know a ton about `ntpd`, but check the settings on the remote host. If its time is also wrong, or its upstream is not set, that could also cause issues. I think ntp has also been known to have issues with `ntpd -gq` if the service is running, so try stopping it first. If nothing else, try `ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com` to fetch time from Canonical's public ntp server. There's also `hwclock --set` or `hwclock --adjust`.

I've also seen mention that ntp will not actually update the date if the discrepancy between your OS time and the upstream's time is too great... though I'm not sure what purpose this has, unless you're intentionally setting the date far in the past or future (a use case which has some valid uses, such as forcibly expiring all user sessions for a service). Try manually setting it to just a few minutes or seconds off the actual time and try updating again.

Comment: If you're seeing these 'not yet activated' messages with wget when building containers in Docker, and you run it on a Windows host, it could be to do with time drift caused by your computer sleeping. There are a few different fixes to try as discussed in this answer here: [Docker container date/time totally different to host PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39984770/docker-container-date-time-totally-different-to-host-pc).