# date() php display wrong date

Tags: php, docker, localhost

I have a problem that persist in my localhost machine.

```
<?php echo date('d/m/Y H:i') ?>
```

this display `28/02/2021 14:13` but we are `Tue Mar 02 2021 11:11:59 GMT+0100 (UTC+01:00)`

I don't know where this problem came from ?

restart docker not resolving it !

here is what I get in docker ssh its the same problem.

```
php >
php >
php > echo date('d/m/Y H:s');
28/02/2021 14:19
php >
```

it should display `02/03/2021 14:19`

Comment: connect to docker via ssh and check the date

Comment: change your default timezone in the ``.php.ini`` file, save and restart the server.

Comment: look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39984770/docker-container-date-time-totally-different-to-host-pc

Comment: I have the right timezone! `Europe/Paris`

Comment: PHP reads time from OS. Are you using WSL2? It has some known issues with Linux time drifting from hardware clock and you  need stuff like `sudo hwclock -s`.