# Rails DateTime.now and Date.current returning date 2 weeks in the past

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, datetime, rails-console

I'm checking DateTime.now and Date.current in rails c but it keeps returning a date almost 2 weeks in the past. Today's date is July 7th, 2021, but I'm getting June 24th, 2021 when I run DateTime.now or Date.current. Any ideas why that could be happening and how I can fix it?

Also, if I run Date.tomorrow it shows Friday June 25th, 2021.

P.s. I am running rails c in a Docker container.

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39984770/7009747

Comment: @SajjadUmar thank you for sharing! I restarted the docker container and restarted computer and now Date is working fine!